# partial mean value theorem

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:X\times Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $f$ is continuously differentiable and $X$ and $Y$ are open sets. I want to apply mean value theorem on $x$ only. Then, I have
 $$ f(x_1,y) - f(x_2,y) = f_x(\tilde{x},y)(x_1-x_2)$$

My question is whether or not $\tilde{x}$ depends on $y$. It is obvious that if $f(\cdot)$ is additively or multicatively separable, then $\tilde{x}$ is invariant to $y$. Also, I consider sine function, $f(x,y) = \sin(xy)$, it seems $\tilde{x}$ is also invariant to $y$.

Comment: How about $e^{xy}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must do in general. Imagine a function which is zero at $x_1$ and $x_2$, and has a maximum that moves with $y$. Actually, there's no need to imagine it: for $x_1=0$ and $x_2=1$, the following is such a function:
$$ f(x,y) = x(1 - x) ((2 - 3 y) y + x (-1 + 2 y)) $$
You can check that $f_x(x,y) $ has a factor of $x-y$ (and moreover, $y=x$ is a maximum if $0<y<1$). The other extremum also depends on $y$, so whichever one you choose, the "Rolle point" where $f_x(\tilde{x},y)=0$ depends on $y$.